# How to assign Stored Procedure to a Parameter that is declared in another stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have stored `proc1` `sp_DateFromRange` which returns date.
I have another stored `proc2` which returns table with other data..`storedproc2` has date parameters `@datefrom` and `@dateto`.

Now, i need to assign `storedproc1` to `@datefrom` in `storedproc2`

Is it possible to assign

Comment: How does `proc1` return the date?  An output parameter, or a result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not, it's not possible the way you wished.

Here's interesting article on how to share data between stored procedures

[How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

In my opinion, the simplest way is to use **output parameter** or **temp table**. For more info check the link. Here's a simple way of using output parameter.

```
DECLARE @datefrom smalldatetime

Exec storedproc1 @datefrom OUTPUT 

Exec storedproc2 @datefrom
```

Here's another simple example of using temp table for getting result set from a stored procedure

```
DECLARE @datefrom smalldatetime

CREATE TABLE #tmp (dateFrom smalldatetime)

INSERT #tmp
EXEC storedproc1

SELECT TOP 1 @datefrom = dateFrom FROM #tmp 

Exec storedproc2 @datefrom
```

You could also use **shared temp table**. You will find implementation in article I've provided.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `@datefrom` must be an output parameter in `sp_DateFromRange`:

```
create procedure DateFromRange(
  @datefrom datetime = null output
)
as begin
--body
end
```

and you can try:

```
declare @date datetime

exec sp_DateFromRange @date out

exec storedproc2 @datefrom = @date ,  @dateto = @value
or
exec storedproc2 @date,  @value
```

EDIT:

**using result set**

```
declare @date datetime

exec @date = sp_DateFromRange

exec storedproc2 @datefrom = @date ,  @dateto = @value
or
exec storedproc2 @date,  @value
```

Comment: The OP has now commented that the date is in a result set

Comment: @Andomar He could change it to an output parameter if it's possible and is more comfortable solution for him.

Comment: @hgulyan has right. Output parameter is better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert ... exec` to capture the output set of a stored procedure.  The definition of the table you're inserting into has to match the output of the stored procedure exactly.

For example:

```
if object_id('proc1') is not null
    drop procedure proc1
if object_id('proc2') is not null
    drop procedure proc2
go
create procedure proc1
as
select getdate() as col1
go
create procedure proc2
    @col2 datetime
as
print 'Col2 = ' + cast(@col2 as varchar(24))
go
declare @sp_result table (col1 datetime)

insert  @sp_result
exec    proc1

declare @col1 datetime
select  @col1 = col1
from    @sp_result

exec proc2 @col1
```

This prints:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Col2 = Sep 13 2012  9:11AM
```